# What is devops meaning ? What requirement?

Tags: computer-science

I wonder about devops web development? Can anyone tell me about this please?

What is devops? What language should I learn?

I want to know what language to learn in order to complete.

If it is same as backend developer? Or what else?

Comment: [Wikipedia on DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) - it's not about any particular language to learn - it's a **principle**